# Are Grails getDirtyPropertyNames and getPersistentValue supported by MongDB?

Tags: mongodb, grails

I am using Grails version 2.4.2 and MongoDB 2.6
Created a Domain class Foo

```
class Foo {
  String slug
  String name
  String toString(){
    "${name}"
  }
  static constraints = {
    name blank: false
  }
  @Override
  def beforeUpdate(){
  if(isDirty("slug"){
    println "beforeUpdate() current value is  " +  this.slug
    println "original property names that were changed = " +     this.getDirtyPropertyNames()
    println "original value = " + this.getPersistentValue("slug")
  } 
 }
}
```

I created a FooController with scaffolding

```
class FooController{
  static scaffold = true
}
```

I run the app and create a new foo enter a *name* field and a *slug* field value  then update the *slug* field

**Are these methods supported by MongoDB?**
[getPersistentValue](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/getPersistentValue.html)
[getDirtyPropertyNames](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/getDirtyPropertyNames.html)

Comment: >beforeUpate() current value is abcde
>
>original property names were changed =[]
>
>original value  = null

Comment: Console output <br> >beforeUpate() current value is abcde<br>
>
>original property names were changed =[]<br>
>
>original value  = null<br>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the Grails MongoDB plugin from `:mongodb:3.0.1` to the latest version which is `3.0.3` right now. That fixed it, now  `getPersistentValue()` and `getDirtyPropertyNames()` methods both work with MongoDB.